# show label in ajax .net

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I am trying to show hidden label after i clikk on a button.
I searched google and tried some things but nothing seems to work.

```
                 $("#lblUserNotExists").show();
                 $("#lblUserNotExists").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

after i click it nothing happan.
Can someone help?

```
       if (response.d != "") {

                <%-- '<%Session["userId"] = "' response.d '" ; %>';--%>
                 window.location = "WelcomePage.aspx";
             }
             else if (response.d == "") {
                // here i need the label to show.
             }
```

Comment: And did you add jQuery, a DOM ready handler, and a click event handler for the button ?

Comment: Yes. I have: OnClientClick="LoginUser();return false".. this is a working projet which i just enterd my code.